# Is there any geth -- fast equivalent for pyethapp?

Tags: synchronization, pyethapp

I tried to   " pyethapp run " but I am    " INFO:p2p.peermgr    waiting for bootstrap " for hours. Anything I could try to have the blockchain as fast as geth -- fast for pyethapp? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message you're seeing is from the [pydevp2p](https://github.com/ethereum/pydevp2p) p2p networking library, which is used for peer discovery. Your node sits in [`_discovery_loop()`](https://github.com/ethereum/pydevp2p/blob/9f51bd3a1926144d255d42ae5d52d09e09ac8a15/devp2p/peermanager.py#L172) while it tries to discover a minimum number of peers from which to sync the blockchain.

In this case, having a Pyethapp equivalent of Geth's `--fast` flag wouldn't help. The `--fast` option helps speed up the sync of the blockchain by only downloading the block headers, thereby reducing the amount of data being synced.

Your node never gets to the stage of actually starting the blockchain sync - your problem is the more fundamental one of not having found anyone to sync the data from yet.

With regards to the problem of waiting for peers, [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/4339/52) previous answer basically says "wait a until your node finds some".